# Getting the error inside XSL:when condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have fetch an value as shown below..

```
<xsl:variable name="begtt">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($try_obj/@segReference,6)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

now I need to check that whether `begtt` =0 or not

so I am using like this but please advise it is the correct approach..

```
<xsl:when test="$begtt="'0'">
<xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
```

As I am getting the error

Comment: It looks like you forgot to tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extraneous `"` in the middle. Try this:

```
<xsl:when test="$begtt = '0'">
```